# How to extract text between quotes with regex in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following string and I want to extract the text between single quotes.

```
javascriptfunction('marie d\'avignon','-','','3')
```

The problem for me is the escaped single quote (there might be multiple occurrences of escaped characters), so the match should be

```
marie d\'avignon
-
3
```

Help is appreciated

Comment: so you want to print the string within single quotes which contain escaped single quotes?

Comment: right, the escaped quote should be included in the extracted string

Comment: does it contain more than one escaped quotes? Please update your question with more details..

Comment: What would be the output for `javascriptfunction('marie d\'avignon','-','','3', 'foo\'bar\'')` input?

Comment: Is it to run in javascript or ruby?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex,

```
(?<=')(?:[^']*\\')+[^']*(?=')
```

[DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/TTEySFDN6H)

`(?:[^']*\\')+` regex ensures that there must be an escaped quote present inside the quoted string.

Comment: nice, but what about matches of the two other strings. In the example from above '-', '', '3' ? The regex you have just matches the first group?

Comment: You said that you want only the string which contains escaped quotes.

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the question. Your help is appreciated

Comment: Why you don't want the empty string?

Comment: @dc10 see here http://rubular.com/r/ZK593J0EiX . Get the values from group index 1.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is probably:

```
str = "javascriptfunction('marie d\\'avignon','-','','3')"
#=> "javascriptfunction('marie d\\'avignon','-','','3')"
str[/'.*?(?<!\\)'/]
#=> "'marie d\\'avignon'"
str.scan /'(.*?(?<!\\))'/
#=> [["marie d\\'avignon"], ["-"], [""], ["3"]]
```